# Error in executing Paypal Payment in Android

Tags: java, android, paypal

I am trying to execute "Pay with PayPal" button in my app.

Here is the code when I click on this button:

```
class PaypalTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        protected final char[] TOTAL_GBP=null;

        public Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            ppObject = PayPal.initWithAppID(getBaseContext(), "APP-80W284485P519543T", PayPal.ENV_SANDBOX);

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            btnPaypal = ppObject.getCheckoutButton(getApplicationContext(), PayPal.BUTTON_278x43, CheckoutButton.TEXT_PAY);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
            params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);
            btnPaypal.setLayoutParams(params);
            rlPay.addView(btnPaypal);
            if(utils.prefs.getBoolean("isLogged", false)) btnPaypal.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); else btnPaypal.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            btnPaypal.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    // to check whether there are any books in the shopping cart
                    if(!cid.isEmpty()){
                        PayPalPayment payment = new PayPalPayment();
                        payment.setSubtotal(new BigDecimal(TOTAL_GBP));
                        payment.setCurrencyType("GBP");
                        payment.setRecipient(Utils.PAYPAL_ACCOUNT);
                        payment.setPaymentType(PayPal.PAYMENT_TYPE_GOODS);
                        Intent checkoutIntent = PayPal.getInstance().checkout(payment, getBaseContext());
                        startActivityForResult(checkoutIntent, 1);
                    }else{
                        utils.showToast("Your shopping cart is empty.");
                        // The PayPal button needs to be updated so that the user can click on it again.
                        btnPaypal.updateButton();
                    }
                }   
            });
        }
    }
```

I am getting the following errors in Log Cat:

```
03-23 11:56:33.539: E/AndroidRuntime(739): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-23 11:56:33.539: E/AndroidRuntime(739): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-23 11:56:33.539: E/AndroidRuntime(739):  at java.math.BigDecimal.<init>(BigDecimal.java:406)
03-23 11:56:33.539: E/AndroidRuntime(739):  at com.fokrul.justdeals.ActivityTab$PaypalTask$1.onClick(ActivityTab.java:1587)
03-23 11:56:33.539: E/AndroidRuntime(739):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3110)
03-23 11:56:33.539: E/AndroidRuntime(739):  at com.paypal.android.MEP.CheckoutButton.onClick(Unknown Source)
03-23 11:56:33.539: E/AndroidRuntime(739):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3110)
03-23 11:56:33.539: E/AndroidRuntime(739):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:11934)
03-23 11:56:33.539: E/AndroidRuntime(739):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
03-23 11:56:33.539: E/AndroidRuntime(739):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-23 11:56:33.539: E/AndroidRuntime(739):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
03-23 11:56:33.539: E/AndroidRuntime(739):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4123)
03-23 11:56:33.539: E/AndroidRuntime(739):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-23 11:56:33.539: E/AndroidRuntime(739):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
03-23 11:56:33.539: E/AndroidRuntime(739):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
03-23 11:56:33.539: E/AndroidRuntime(739):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
03-23 11:56:33.539: E/AndroidRuntime(739):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I have found out that It is because may be I assigned NULL value to TOTAL_GBP.

And if I change it to this:

```
payment.setSubtotal(new BigDecimal("8.25"));
```

It works but shows £8.25 as checkout value. But I want it to get value from cart sub total defined by TOTAL_GBP. It simply crashes when I use TOTAL_GBP instead of "8.25" or any double float value.

Any thoughts?

Comment: `TOTAL_GBP` is `null` because you haven't assigned a value to it!

Comment: Shouldnt it be getting value from the cart sub total? Is there another way of assigning value to it? example would be helpful.